# Add Button Value into all Text Box in a For Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, button

I have a quick question. I have a form with a for loop. Each for loop has a text box. I want to have two buttons that when I click on one, all the text boxes get populated with the value in the button. For example, when I click on the button "Add 50 minutes," I want all my text boxes to populate with 50. The same goes for if I click on the button "Add 110 minutes" (Screen shot attached)

[image]

Here is my form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Minutes", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-date", onsubmit = "popup()" }))
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <table id="tablereport" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                <thead style="background-color:black; font-weight:bold; color:aliceblue">
                    <tr>

                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>@Html.Label("Date :")</b></td>

                    <td>@Html.TextBox("datepicker", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new { required = "required" })</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="btnSetText" value="Add 50 Minutes" class="btn btn-default" onclick="setText" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Add 110 Minutes" class="btn btn-default" /></td>

                </tr>



            </table>
        </div>
        @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
            <div id="dialog-message" title="Alert !!">
                <p>
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
                    @ViewBag.Message
                </p>
            </div>
        }

        <table id="tablereport" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead style="background-color:black; font-weight:bold; color:aliceblue">
                <tr>

            </thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Class ID</th>
                <th>Course Title</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>SID</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Minutes</th>
            </tr>

            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {

                <tr>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].ClassID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].ClassID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].CourseTitle)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].CourseTitle)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Department)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Department)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].SID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].SID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].FullName)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].FullName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].Minutes, new { @Value = "0" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].Minutes)
                    </td>

                </tr>

            }

        </table>

        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="popup()" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </fieldset>
}
```

Here is my script

```
<script>

var date = new Date();
var maxdate = date.getDate();
//var currentDate = $(".selector").datepicker("getDate");
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        defaultDate: maxdate,
        minDate: '-1M',
        maxDate: '+0D'
    });
});

**function setText(){

  var setText = document.getElementById('setText');

  setText.value = '50';
}**
```

The script I have is working, but will only populate one text box.

Thank you!!

Comment: The setText id is for which element? The textbox?

Comment: @Borka - Yes, the setTextID for my textbox

Comment: As a side note, never set the `value` attribute when using `HtmlHelper` methods. Remove your `new { @Value = "0" }` (if `Minutes` is typeof `int` then it will be `0` anyway, or if you want a different value, then set the value of `Minutes` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the ids should be unique for every element in the DOM. Even though in your case there's more than one element with the same id the `document.getElementById()` function returns one element(the first one with that id). What you want to do is add a class to each textbox and then use `document.getElementsByClassName()` which will return a list of all the elements that have the class.

For example:

```js
$("#add-50").on('click', function() {
    // ill intentionally use vanilla js here
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('textbox');

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      var input1 = inputs[i];
      input1.value = '50';
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="add-50">Click Me for 50</button><br/>
  <input class="textbox" type="text" /><br/>
  <input class="textbox" type="text" /><br/>
  <input class="textbox" type="text" /><br/>
  <input class="textbox" type="text" /><br/>
  <input class="textbox" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all the textboxes in a div, add a class to all of them and then use something like this: 
`function setValue(value){
$('#divWithtextboxes .TextboxClass').each(function (i) {
    $(this).val(value);
<br>
});<br>`